# Moving externally owned files/folders in Google Workspace Shared Drives

Tags: google-drive-api, google-admin-sdk, google-drive-shared-drive

While attempting to migrate folders that contain data owned by external users, we've ran into an error with moving a folder from My Drive to a Shared Drive.   We understand the limitation of moving a folder containing a certain amount of “unmovable files”.

It appears there is no easy way around this, and updating the permissions of the files by the external owner or downloading the files and re-uploading the files to the new location in the Shared Drives are the best options.

We wanted to ask if anyone has found a process to simplify manually performing this for many files/folders that exist in my org's Google My Drive?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.